# Python eval() exception handling in one line

Tags: python, try-catch, eval

I am programming an IRC bot in python. All code is in one line. I know that this is not how python programs should be written, but this is experimental. I want to execute oneliner scripts from IRC, but I don't know how to handle exceptions.

Is it possible to evaluate a python expression and handle possible exceptions in one line? AFAIK try-except does not work in one line.

Here is the current code: http://pastebin.com/f34brq91.
It is not very easy to read that, but it is not necessary to understand it to answer my question. :)

Comment: Im just going to leave this here http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201206/eval_really_is_dangerous.html

Comment: This question will not benefit the community, it is promoting bad-practice, and unsafe programming. Previously, this would have been closed as a "Too Local" question.

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to put an exception handler in one line. You can only put simple statements on one line, and `try` - `except` is a compound statement.

There are also no functions that'll swallow exception for you.

The only way you'd be able to pull something like this off in one line, is to create a new code object from raw bytes that define the bytecodes for a blanket `try` - `except: pass` construct. Using that bytecode you would then go on to create a function that swallows exceptions.

However, I am not going to write one for you. Sorry.

Comment: I found a way: eval(compile('def exc(function, catch_function, e=Exception):\n try:\n '+' function()\n except e:\n '+' catch_function()', '', 'exec'))